# Implement long-term processing with App Engine/Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to implement a backend in which:

- Mobile app uploads data to App Engine based server (written in Python)
- Server processes data
- Server send a push notification to mobile app to notify data processing completed
- Mobile app downloads processing result from App Engine

Which is the best way to implement upload/data processing on App Enging using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Google Cloud Storage with Blobstore API to upload.

The flow would be:

1. Mobile app calls [create_upload_url](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Uploading_a_blob)
2. Mobile app uploads the file then on the upload handler start a [taskqueue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred) (I linked to deferred library, it simplifies the creation of taskqueue.
3. In the end of the task, call the push notification api and send some key data for download
4. Mobile app receives the key and you create a download request.